# How to only concatenate JS files with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I used to use gulp for merge few static linked JS libraries files into one.

I've installed webpack and add react and few libraries as npm module. It works fine.

Now I want to completely remove gulp so I need to ONLY concatenate JS libraries (lot of jquery plugins and old 1.8 jquery itself). I don't want to install these JS libraries via npm, because it will be too much work.

When I use webpack to bundle these libraries it doesn't work, because webpack wrap these libraries and I can't use these without add requires.

Could you please tell me how to ONLY concatenate JS files into one with webpack?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Webpack is module bundler and that is how it works. If you just want to merge many js file into one then just use another tools like gulp. Webpack is much more.